# MergeSort - ArraysOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, sorting, junit4, mergesort

Was studying sorting algorithms via a free online course where the instructor was using the main() method to show how to print the results.

Decided to use a JUnit test instead a main method.

However, I am getting the following StackTrace:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 8
    at MergeSort.sort(MergeSort.java:30)
    at MergeSort.sort(MergeSort.java:14)
    at MergeSort.sort(MergeSort.java:14)
    at MergeSortTest.sort(MergeSortTest.java:14)
```

MergeSort.java (actual implementation):

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class MergeSort {

    public static String sort(int[] array, int[] tmpArray, int lowIndex, int highIndex) {
        int midIndex =0;
        int lowIndex1 = 0;
        int lowIndex2 = 0;
        int i = 0;

        // Divide up sets using recursion
        if (highIndex > lowIndex) {
            midIndex = (highIndex + lowIndex) / 2;
            sort(array, tmpArray, lowIndex, midIndex);
            sort(array, tmpArray, midIndex + 1, highIndex);
        }

        lowIndex1 = lowIndex;
        lowIndex2 = midIndex+1;

        System.arraycopy(array, 0, tmpArray, 0, array.length);

        // Merge elements
        while(lowIndex <= midIndex && lowIndex2 <= highIndex) {
            if (tmpArray[lowIndex1] <= tmpArray[lowIndex2]) {
                array[i] = tmpArray[lowIndex1];
                lowIndex1++;
            }
            else {
                array[i] = tmpArray[lowIndex2];
            }
            i++;
        }
        while (lowIndex1 <= midIndex) {
            array[i] = tmpArray[lowIndex1];
            i++;
            lowIndex1++;
        }
        while (lowIndex2 <= highIndex) {
            array[i] = tmpArray[lowIndex2];
            i++;
            lowIndex2++;
        }
        return Arrays.toString(array);
    }
}
```

MergeSortTest.java:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.junit.Test;

public class MergeSortTest {

    int[] array = new int[] {6, 4, 10, 9, 3, 7, 2, 1};
    int[] sortedArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9, 10};
    int[] tmp = new int[array.length];

    @Test
    public void sort() {
        System.out.println("Unsorted array: " + Arrays.toString(array));
        String value = MergeSort.sort(array, tmp, 0, array.length - 1);
        assert(value == Arrays.toString(sortedArray));
        System.out.println("Sorted array: " + value);
    }
}
```

What am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
// Merge elements
        while(lowIndex <= midIndex && lowIndex2 <= highIndex) {
            if (tmpArray[lowIndex1] <= tmpArray[lowIndex2]) {
                array[i] = tmpArray[lowIndex1];
                lowIndex1++;
            }
            else {
                array[i] = tmpArray[lowIndex2];
            }
            i++;
        }
```

should be

```
// Merge elements
        while(lowIndex <= midIndex && lowIndex2 <= highIndex) {
            if (tmpArray[lowIndex1] <= tmpArray[lowIndex2]) {
                array[i] = tmpArray[lowIndex1];
                lowIndex1++;
            }
            else {
                array[i] = tmpArray[lowIndex2];
                lowIndex2++; // add this one
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you but it now throws the same exception but at line 25.

Answer (score 0):

I found four problems with your merge-sort implementation.

Firstly, the condition in the following `while` loop is incorrect:

```
    // Merge elements
    while(lowIndex <= midIndex && lowIndex2 <= highIndex) {
```

You are incrementing `lowIndex1` within the loop, not `lowIndex`, so the loop should look like the following:

```
    // Merge elements
    while(lowIndex1 <= midIndex && lowIndex2 <= highIndex) {
```

Secondly, as pointed out by @andy, you need to increment `lowIndex2` in the `else` clause of the `if` statement within your `while` loop.

Thirdly, you are using the variable `i` to keep track of where to write back into `array` the sorted values from merging the two sorted subsections of your array.  Your `sort` method sorts the section of the array from `lowIndex` to `highIndex` inclusive, so you need to initialise `i` to `lowIndex`, not `0`, to ensure that your code writes the merged elements in the right place in `array`.

Finally, what should happen if `highIndex` equals `lowIndex`?  In this case, you are sorting a single-element section of your array.  As it stands, your code will leave `midIndex` set to 0.  The rest of your code requires `midIndex` to be between `lowIndex` and `highIndex`, and if `lowIndex` is greater than 0 this will no longer be true.  Of course, you can sort a 1-element collection by doing nothing, so in this situation it's okay to skip the merging.  I'd recommend adding a `return` statement in an `else` clause:

```
   if (highIndex > lowIndex) {
        midIndex = (highIndex + lowIndex) / 2;
        sort(array, tmpArray, lowIndex, midIndex);
        sort(array, tmpArray, midIndex + 1, highIndex);
    } else {
        // Nothing to do, we only have one element to sort
        return Arrays.toString(array);
    }
```

I made these four changes to your code and found that your JUnit test passed.  I also wrote extra tests for other arrays and found that these passed too.